# Why can't Windows Mail app display email content properly?

Tags: email, imap, windows-mail, windows-8-mail-app, windows-10-mail-app

```
Received: from localhost (unknown [99.231.89.90])
by mail-m11883.qiye.163.com (Hmail) with ESMTPA id BD1498401A0
for <mia@aedo.ntesmail.com>; Mon, 29 May 2023 13:09:56 +0800 (CST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 29 May 2023 01:09:52 -0400
From: Aedo Test <hansen@aedo.ntesmail.com>
Subject: This is a test email
Thread-Topic: This is a test email
Message-ID: <E1DDF9EB-2580-2A49-B535-3DA3B6842E4D@hxcore.ol>
To: <mia@aedo.ntesmail.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
X-HM-Spam-Status: e1kfGhgUHx5ZQUpXWQgPGg8OCBgUHx5ZQUlOS1dZFg8aDwILHllBWSg2Ly
    tZV1koWUFDSUNOSEhLS043V1ktWUFJV1kPCRoVCBIfWUFZGh4aGFZNTUMdQklCTUkdSkpVAhYTFh
    oSFyQUDg9ZV1kYEgtZQVlCQlVJSEpVQ0JVQktZV1kWGg8SFR0UWUFZT0tIVUpOTUlPSVVKS0tVS1
    kG
X-HM-Tid: 0a8865e9bcc62eb8kusnbd1498401a0
X-HM-MType: 4
X-HM-Sender-Digest: e1kMHhlZQR0aFwgeV1kSHx4VD1lBWUc6Phw6Fhw6Gj0XP08oFBAUHxpO
    Kz4wC0hVSlVKTUNOSEhNQkJMTE1IVTMWGhIXVRMaFQgeFTsaHh8UVRUPHggWGhIXVRgUFkVZV1kS
    C1lBWUJCVUlISlVDQlVCS1lXWQgBWUFDSkM3Bg++
```

Original Email Screenshot:
[image: Original Email Screenshot]

**My system is Win 10 and I've configured my email in Windows Mail App using IMAP/SMTP setting. This is a test email and the content can be properly displayed on web end but in this App the content is missing and replaced by information above. Is there anything wrong on my setting?**

Comment: the screenshot looks identical to the text in the question - did you link to the wrong image?

Comment: They should be the same. I just want to explain the question visually.